# Confused with より

Tags: particle-より

I'm translating a song from 池森秀一 DEEN and I came across this sentence:

> > 生きてゆきたい　今日より明日へ

And I got confused because my translation was **'I want to keep living, from today to/towards tomorrow'.**

I know より can be used as *since* and *than* depending on context. I checked other translation from a Japanese friend and he said that the correct trans would be:

> > But I want to live on, more for tomorrow than today.

Can you help me understand why my translation is wrong?

Comment: I think it is probably according to the feeling with the language and the context because both translations are grammatically good (https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A). With the previous lines of the song, maybe your friend determined this translation was the more natural one.

Comment: Can you tell the name of the song?

Comment: Sure. 「ひとりじゃない」by DEEN. It is the ending for Dragon Ball GT You can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcwslI5uQrc) (0:25)

Comment: It's "Carpe diem."

Answer (score 3):

This 今日より明日へ implies "toward the future". I think "more for tomorrow than today" can imply more it than "from today to tomorrow". "from today to tomorrow" implies just a short future time, doesn't it? It would be translated as 今日から明日へ.